# Почему неявная специализация шаблона не генерируется автоматически?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

При создании динамически подключаемой библиотеки, содержащей статические переменные, доступные для всех процессов, подключающих ее образ, мне потребовалась следующая структура для работы с данными переменными:

```
template<typename T>
struct XO_DLL Property
{
protected:
    T volatile m_value;
public:
    Property(T value);
    void SetValue(T value);
    T GetValue();
    __declspec(property(get = GetValue, put = SetValue)) T Value;
};
```

Здесь же в библиотеке объявляются оные переменные:

```
#pragma section(".xo", read, write, shared)
#define SHARED __declspec(allocate(".xo"))

SHARED Property<int> g_turns = Property<int>(127);
```

Библиотека компилируется, но при компилировании основного приложения выдается следующее:

```
Main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall Property<int>::GetValue(void)" (__imp_?GetValue@?$Property@H@@QAEHXZ) в функции _main.
Main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
```

Говоря иначе, «в библиотеке отсутствует специализация метода `GetValue` для `T = int`». Ошибка исчезает, если явно объявить данную специализацию (в дополнение к общей):

```
template<typename T>
T Property<T>::GetValue()
{
    return m_value;
}

int Property<int>::GetValue()
{
    return m_value;
}
```

> Про идентичный проблемному `SetValue` промолчу: работает и хорошо.

Почему компилятор после объявления переменной типа `Property<int>` не генерирует данную специализацию `Property<int>::GetValue` самостоятельно на основе общей специализации `Property<T>::GetValue`?

---

[**Демонстрационный проект**](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9qiW/mxcDMQ1P6)

Comment: @LShadow77, переменная объявляется в той же библиотеке, что и реализация общей специализации `T Property<T>::GetValue()`; иначе, было бы больше одного неразрешенного внешнего символа.

Comment: Добавление строки `template class Property<int>;` в демонстрационном проекте после объявления структуры в `Property.h` значительно помогло: компилятор неявно реализовал проблемную специализацию. То есть теперь достаточно написать одну строку для каждого типа.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicit-instantiation?view=msvc-170